Would a question like, "How can I make an Amiibo from an NFC card?" be allowed in Game Development?
I want to ask how to make an amiibo out of NFC cards, but Im not 100% sure if this kind of question is allowed here. Would this be ok in Game Development? If not, where should I go to ask this question?

Yes.  In fact, there are already several questions about Amiibo development.
This is assuming the question meets the normal critera as can be seen in the tour and the help guide.
